# Populate Dropdown options using php code in a docusign template before creating envelope

Tags: php, laravel, docusignapi, docusignconnect, docusign-sdk

Is any who implemented Dropdown[image]

How can I implement it in Laravel?
Like $service = new Text([....]); How can we implement Dropdown in DocuSign
The dropdown class is not available in
"composer require docusign/esign-client" package so how can I import dropdown class
Thanks in advance for the guide or code

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called `ListTab`, so you need to look for List.
In PHP it's called `ModelList`, you can find the code in https://github.com/docusign/docusign-esign-php-client/blob/master/src/Model/ModelList.php

So you add a `ListTab` to the Tabs object and that object is instantiated as a `ModelList` class.

Comment: Thanks for responding, I am a bit confused about how to list items to my ModelList initializing. I've searched for further understanding but couldn't able to get any help from any of the documentation.

Comment: `$dropdown2 = new ModelList(['document_id' => '1', 'height' => "10",  'list_items' =>  '',
            'list_selected_value' => null, 'list_selected_value_metadata' => '', 'page_number' => '1', 'required' => "true", 'tab_label_metadata' => '', 'tooltip' => 'Dropdown','value' => '','value_metadata' => null, 'width' => "130",  'width_metadata' => null,'x_position' => '194',  'x_position_metadata' => null,'y_position' => '71', 'y_position_metadata' => null]);`

Comment: `use DocuSign\eSign\Model\ModelList;
use Docusign\eSign\Model\lineItems;
use DocuSign\eSign\Model\ListItem;
use DocuSign\eSign\Model\ListCustomField;`  I have includes these classes

Comment: But still not get solutions can you please elaborate the things to clarify the thind

Comment: Please have a look on screenshot https://prnt.sc/dJChxCu78Ylt

Comment: what happens what you run this code?

Comment: Is the screenshot what you want? or what the code does?

Comment: Please have a look on screenshot 

https://prnt.sc/wZxzuWd4ubCI

Comment: I want  like this https://prnt.sc/QylPf6QVEiLD

Comment: I just wanted to show a simple dropdown just like we used to do in html.  Dropdown will have 3 options for eg: 

List Item 1

List Item 2

List Item 3


**When I run this code it doesn't do anything.**


So in my eSign document user can select any on List Item.

Comment: In this code snippet, you would need to replace the following values with your own:

ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE: This is the access token for your DocuSign API integration.
ENVELOPE_ID_HERE: This is the ID of the envelope that you want to add the dropdown list to.
RECIPIENT_ID_HERE: This is the ID of the recipient who will see the dropdown list in the envelope.

Once you have replaced these values, you can save the code snippet to an HTML file and open it in your web browser to see the button that will add the dropdown list to your DocuSign document when clicked.

Comment: so, the code doesn't work at all? or it works but you don't see a dropdown?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253504/discussion-between-manish-kumar-pathak-and-inbar-gazit).